# Android Gallery doesn't get refreshed Using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I have use this Intent for Refreshing the Gallery ........

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Everything works perfectly but after deleting, the image is still shown when pressing the back button. The gallery is refreshing only if I quit the currently opened gallery and reopen it. Please help, and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

This has never been a good way to "refresh gallery".

Use [`MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) instead for notifying the system of changes in media files in the filesystem.

Comment: laalto , thanks for your answer ...kindly explain how  i can use  MediaScannerConnection ..